# MeetUp en ciudad de Buenos Aires - 4 de Mayo 19:00 hs (zona microcentro)

Tags: discusión, encuentros-locales

Amigos!

El proximo 4 de mayo, a las 19:00 hs iniciamos la Meetup de BSAS. Estan todos invitados!

Nos visita [Gervasio Marchand](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/11272/g3rv4), desarrollador en Stack Overflow Jobs, un uruguayo que nació en Argentina y que viene para contarnos:

- Cómo es trabajar para Stack Overflow, con un equipo de desarrolladores, diseñadores y PMs distribuidos por todo el mundo.
- Cómo Stack Overflow usa Data Science para entender a los usuarios y decidir qué desarrollar (además de... para encontrar bugs!)

Los [esperamos](https://www.meetup.com/StackOverflow-en-Espanol-Buenos-Aires/events/239465138/).

ACTUALIZACION:

La reunion sera grabada, estamos intentando transmitira en vivo, pero en caso de no llegar a tiempo la vamos a publicar en YouTube tan pronto como sea posible.

Comment: ¿Habrá transmisión online?

Comment: @Flxtr es la idea, pero no esta confirmado. Falta asegurar los recursos para hacerlo. Si se confirma voy a editar el post con tiempo para dejar los links de acceso.

Comment: Buenísimo, espero no olvidarme, creo que será genial, cualquier cosa me sacan a los pelos.

Comment: Espero que fuera un éxito :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Y lo prometido es deuda.

[Algunas fotos de evento.](https://www.meetup.com/StackOverflow-en-Espanol-Buenos-Aires/photos/all_photos/?photoAlbumId=27825727)

#### Y los videos...

Nos visitó [Gervasio Marchand](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/11272/g3rv4), desarrollador en Stack Overflow Jobs y dio estas dos charlas a continuación...

- [Cómo es trabajar para Stack Overflow](https://youtu.be/NbqhbcFmZrc), con un equipo de desarrolladores, diseñadores y PMs distribuidos por todo el mundo.
- [Cómo Stack Overflow usa Data Science](https://youtu.be/NXlCmq7GbrA) para entender a los usuarios y decidir qué desarrollar (además de... para encontrar bugs!)

<sub>nota: algo salio mal durante la grabación resultando en algunos problemas de calidad de audio y video, sepan disculpar los inconvenientes.</sub>