# Presentación del sitio para eventos

Tags: discusión, promoción-del-sitio

*Mi proposito en esta pregunta es hacer una propuesta que podría servirnos en general como usuarios activos de esta comunidad.*

#### Antecedentes

En mi ciudad, hace algunos meses se creó una comunidad de desarrolladores, programadores, estudiantes de computacion, entusiastas.

Cada dos a tres semanas se realizan *meetups* con el proposito de reunirse y charlar un poco, hacer tutoriales, pequeñas conferencias, discutir acerca de nuevas tecnologias, frameworks, etc.

Uno de los organizadores del evento, con quien he charlado acerca de la comunidad de **Stack Overflow en español**, me ha dicho que seria muy bueno que durante el encuentro se tomaran algunos minutos para hacer una presentacion del sitio, debido a que muchas de las personas conocen **Stack Overflow... inglés**. Por lo cual, considera que puede ser una buena iniciativa para **hacer conocer el sitio, motivar a la gente a participar y asi hacer crecer la comunidad**.

#### Idea

La idea que ha surgido despues de esto ha sido:

***"Crear una presentacion, que pueda ser usada para hablar de nuestra comunidad, tanto en el entorno laboral como académico."***

#### Propuesta

Lo que propongo inicialmente como un modelo a seguir para diseñar esta presentacion, ***que obviamente será de acceso a todos nosotros para nuestro uso.*** Es el siguiente:

- Introducción *(Descripcion del sitio)*
- Historia
- Filosofía del sitio *(Cómo preguntar, Cómo responder, Objetivo del sitio)*
- Ludificación *(Reputación, Medallas, Privilegios)*
- Por qué usar SOes *(Respecto a qué beneficios obtenemos al usar esta comunidad, el idioma, una comunidad en español, etc)*
- Cómo contribuir *(Para los usuarios que quizá no tengan mucha experiencia respecto a programación)*

#### Pregunta *(Ahora sí vamos al grano)*

Lo que quiero que me ayuden, *para que así entre todos creemos este documento, que será para uso de todos nosotros*, es **con sus/vuestras sugerencias, respecto a cuáles son los puntos que podríamos o no podríamos tocar, durante una presentación de nuestro sitio ante otras personas ajenas a la comunidad, pero que en su gran mayoría podrían ser usuarios potenciales**.

#### Respecto a la propuesta inicial:

***¿Qué consideran que se podria agregar?***

***¿Qué creen que se deba evitar?***

***¿Qué es lo más importante a remarcar sobre nuestra comunidad?***

*Espero no sea una pregunta muy amplia/basada en opiniones, en caso de que deba modificarla, espero los comentarios.*

Comment: Mas que "grano" parece "mazorca" XD . Ya en serio, me parece que has planteado el punto de muy buena forma pero aún siendo que en Meta son válidas las preguntas basadas en opiniones veo que será todo un reto abarcar de forma completa en el tema en el formato de SOes. Sugiero dividir la pregunta en varias partes.

Comment: interesante propuesta amigo.

Comment: En [este](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1856/meetup-en-ciudad-de-buenos-aires-4-de-mayo-1900-hs-zona-microcentro) evento, hice algo remotamente parecido y durante la presentación me base en el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour). Me fue de gran ayuda ya que explica varias de las partes que mencionas. Un buen comienzo, seria escribir un relato que se pueda presentar usando el recorrido en si que ya es una presentación bastante buena.

Comment: Sería muy bueno contar con el apoyo de @JuanM para este tipo de cosas.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con @Luiggi. Por ejemplo se podrían compartir las presentaciones para la celebración de la graduación [en México](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1843/83) y [en España](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1844/83).

Comment: Me parece una excelente idea.  Tengo la presentación en mano y puedo compartirla con ustedes.  Lo único que se va a necesitar cambiar es la parte donde platico sobre lo que un gerente de comunidades hace - es casi la mitad de la presentación.  Por eso pienso que hasta sería mejor empezar de nuevo.

Comment: @JuanM Claro, por supuesto que puedes compartirla, asi podemos revisar y proponer un modelo de presentacion.

Comment: @IvanBotero ¿Es en Bogotá dicha comunidad? ¿cuál es el enlace al meetup?

Comment: @Shaz es en Ibague, este es el link https://www.meetup.com/es/IbagueDev/

Comment: @JuanM de hecho también sería interesante ver esa parte de gerente de comunidades. No sé el resto, pero yo no tengo del todo claro cuáles son todas vuestras funciones :))

Comment: Una de las cosas que habría que remarcar es que tanto la temática del sitio como la moderación son realizadas por los propios usuarios de la comunidad. En cuanto a lo que habría que agregar considero que hay que agregar el "modelo de negocio" (cómo se recaudan fondos y cómo se pagan los gastos de desarrollo y operación, monetización, etc), así como la disponibilidad de "data dumps" en SEDE

Comment: @fedorqui estoy en las mismas. Alguna vez se comentó en el [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/30872?m=37112637#37112637) que sería genial que participara en un webcast como panelista para que nos platique esos oscuros secretos de ser un CM :)

Comment: @fedorqui *...cont.* Nota: si logras ver más abajo de la conversación, Juan nos pone un ejemplo en un gif de cómo ser un CM (él es el conductor del bus).

Comment: @Flxtr la verdad es que dan pocas ganas de ser el pobre ciclista :_) En [¿Quiénes forman el Community Team? ¿Qué hacen?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1671/83) traduje la publicación canónica al respecto. Sin embargo, leyéndola me doy cuenta de que es algo genérica y ambigua, por lo que una explicación de Juan M de primera mano sería fantástica, más que nada para saber qué podemos pedirle y qué no.

Comment: @fedorqui ¡claro que sí! sin duda alguna sería algo genial. Esperemos que tenga esto anotado en su lista de pendientes.

Comment: @JuanM ¿hubo alguna novedad al respecto? ¿Podrías compartir las presentaciones? Gracias

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Aporte de referencias, por el momento parcial.

## Introducción

*(Descripcion del sitio)*

Véase [Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)

## Historia

- [Stack Overflow Launches](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2008/09/15/stack-overflow-launches/)
- [Stack Overflow in Spanish](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42810/stack-overflow-in-spanish) (propuesta en Area 51)
- [Stack Overflow se gradúa hoy](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/05/17/stack-overflow-en-espanol-se-gradua-hoy/)
- ...

## Filosofía del sitio

Véase [Nuestro modelo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/stackexchange)

## Ludificación

Véanse:

- [Privilegios](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)
- [Medallas](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)
- [Ligas de reputación](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/381/week/es-stackoverflow)

## Por qué usar SOes

*(Respecto a qué beneficios obtenemos al usar esta comunidad, el idioma, una comunidad en español, etc)*

Véase [¿Cómo puedo motivar a ser parte de esta comunidad a alguien que nunca ha usado Stack Exchange?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/379/65)

## Cómo contribuir

*(Para los usuarios que quizá no tengan mucha experiencia respecto a programación)*

### Como usuario nuevo

*(Incluyendo a los usuarios anónimos)*

Véase [Crear publicaciones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-posts)

### Como usuario registrado

Véase [¿Por qué debo crear una cuenta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/why-register)

## Otros temas

- [¿Cómo es el modelo de negocio de Stack Overflow?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1243/65)

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, basado en el modelo que propones, empezare a realizar la presentacion y posteriormente la publicare para que se puedan hacer observaciones y mejoras.

Comment: No hay de que Ivan. En cuanto a las formas cómo contribuir para los que no tengan mucha experiencia en programación, no estoy del todo seguro si incluir la sugerencia de [traducir FAQ](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1380/65) ¿Qué opinas?

Comment: De hecho estaba pensando incluir la informacion contenida en ese enlace, para indicarlo como un modo de colaborar.

Comment: ¿cuándo piensan hacer la presentación @IvanBotero?

Comment: @IvanBotero ¿Cómo va esta iniciativa? Se ve que have un año se ha propuesto el esquema para la presentación.  ¿Se ha creado ya esto? En qué puedo ayudar?