# Las etiquetas con tildes se reproducen incorrectamente en la versión móvil cuando se edita una pregunta

Tags: bug, estado-completado, etiquetas, ediciones, web-móvil

Ayer accedí al sitio desde mi móvil (sistema Android 4.5) y fui a editar las etiquetas de [una pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2193/83).

Resulta que esta pregunta tiene dos etiquetas: [discusión](/questions/tagged/discusi%c3%b3n) y [promoción-del-sitio](/questions/tagged/promoci%c3%b3n-del-sitio), ambas con una tilde.

Como se ve en la captura de pantalla, la visualización del nombre de las etiquetas en la sección *Etiquetas* está rota, viéndose `discusi&#243;n` y `promoci&#243;n-del-sitio`. Sí, `&#243` [corresponde](https://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html-spec/html-spec_13.html) a `ó`, pero no es pertinente enseñarlo :)

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El efecto que tiene esto es que si se añade una nueva etiqueta y se da a enviar, el sistema bloquea las "nuevas" etiquetas `discusi&#243;n` y `promoci&#243;n-del-sitio`. Para que se pueda editar, hay que eliminarlas todas e incluirlas de nuevo. En ese momento sí se escriben correctamente.

Nótese que esto ya se reportó en noviembre de 2015 en Meta Stack Exchange: 
[Accented tags not displayed properly on edit page on mobile web site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/268826/209901) para el sitio francés. Creo que sería pertinente revisarlo ahora con más motivo, pues afecta a un sitio tan grande como este. También ocurre en Spanish.SE: [Questions with tags containing accent marks break those on editing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/307310/209901)

Comment: Gracias por reportar esto. Voy a investigar que se puede hacer al respecto. Necesitamos tener uso de las tildes en nuestros dispositivos también. Se ha reportado esto y se esta investigando todavía. Disculpen la demora.

Comment: Generalmente no edito en el móvil pero ayer lo itenté y no pude guardar mi edición por lo que aquí se describe.

Comment: Tienen razón los dos. He removido esa etiqueta 

Comment: Qué es *Android 4.5*? Nunca lo he oído. Tal vez se refiere *Android 4.4* o *5.0*.

Comment: Jaja. Igual, este es un error que es independiente de la versión de Android. Las etiquetas aparecen codificadas en entidades HTML en cualquier edición dentro de la web mobile, y no se acepta publicar etiquetas con entidades HTML. Repro en Android O en esta misma pregunta.

Comment: @Juan es una grandísima noticia que esto pueda quedar resuelto. De momento yo lo veo igual cuando voy a editar la pregunta mencionada vía móvil https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OpG4.png

Comment: @fedorqui Lo he reportado de nuevo. Avisaré en cuanto tenga noticias.

Comment: Esto se ha corregido.

Comment: @Juan fantástico!!!!! Funciona genial, qué bien. En MetaSE también estaba reportado, por si queréis marcarlo como completado también allí: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268826/accented-tags-not-displayed-properly-on-edit-page-on-mobile-web-site

Comment: @fedorqui Gracias por tu paciencia.  He editado el otro reporte también. :)